# Deploying new contract inside truffle test case

Tags: truffle, javascript, testing, truffle-test

I was trying to transact between two contracts inside my truffle test case. But not been able to do it. The second contract instance comes back undefined always.

As per the [truffle documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#add-a-new-contract-to-the-network), deploying new contract inside a test case is as shown below,
`Contract2.new().then(function(instance) { contract2Instance = instance; });`

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined` on `Contract2Address = contract2Instance.address;`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var Contract1 = artifacts.require("./Contract1.sol");
var Contract2 = artifacts.require("./Contract2.sol");

contract('Contract1', function(accounts) {
  it("should put 30000000 in the second account", function() {
    var contract1Instance;
    var contract2Instance;

    var Contract1Address;
    var Contract2Address;

    return Contract1.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      contract1Instance = instance;
      Contract1Address = contract1Instance.address;  
      console.log("Contract1Address:" + Contract1Address);
      Contract2.new().then(function(instance) { contract2Instance = instance; });
      console.log("contract2Instance:" + contract2Instance);
      Contract2Address = contract2Instance.address;

      contract1Instance.deposit({from: accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(2, "ether") });
      contract2Instance.claim({ value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), gas: 1000000 });
      return web3.eth.getBalance(Contract2Address).toString(10);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal (30000000, 30000000, "30000000 wasn't in the first account");
    });
  });
```

PS: Please pardon the mix of the new and old syntax.
The whole test works in truffle console though.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the address before the variable has been assigned to. See if these comments help:

```
// Contract2.new() runs first.
Contract2.new().then(function(instance) {
    // This assignment runs third (or at any time in the future).
    contract2Instance = instance;
});

// This code runs second.
console.log("contract2Instance:" + contract2Instance);
Contract2Address = contract2Instance.address;
```

Remember that a promise is resolved in the future, so that's when your callback code runs. In the meantime, execution keeps going.

You want something like this instead:

```
return Contract2.new().then(function (contract2Instance) {
  // All the code that requires contract2Instance must be in here.

  contract1Instance.deposit({from: accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(2, "ether") });
  contract2Instance.claim({ value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), gas: 1000000 });
  return web3.eth.getBalance(contract2Instance.address).toString(10);
});
```